# ¿Por qué no puedo crear el archivo .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Presento problemas al crear el archivo .htaccess en windows, cuando le coloco el punto inicial me dice esto a la hora de guardarlo:

> Debe escribir un nombre de archivo.

Esto es cuando lo hago desde un bloc de notas, si lo hago desde un editor como atom todo funciona perfecto ¿Alguien conoce el motivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El procedimiento correcto para poder crear un archivo .htaccess desde el bloc de notas es:

1. Abrir bloc de notas
2. Guardar como
3. Colocarle como nombre .htaccess
4. En tipo elegir **todos los archivos(*)**
5. Idealmente en la parte inferior donde dice codificación elegir UTF-8

Y ya con los pasos anteriores te vas a poder crear el .htaccess sin problemas desde el bloc de notas

> Por defecto no te deja guardar con .htaccess si el tipo es documentos
>   de texto por que asume que .htaccess es la extensión del archivo y que
>   te hace falta el nombre; por eso es ideal hacerlo en la forma que
>   enumero arriba

Comment: Muchas gracias por compartir ese conocimiento.

Comment: de nada cuando tengas otra duda la posteas y si lo se te apoyo

Comment: Pues tengo otra duda pero tengo que esperar como 40 minutos jejeje

Comment: En eso ando, tengo que esperar como 1 minuto también